# How to move the sprite with the movement of background?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, ios4

I am working on a tilemap based game in cocos2d in which the player moves in four directions and I have used four images for the movement of player for example left,right,top and down. My problem is that when my background map change its position or move to other position then my sprite does not change its position. Can anyone tell me how to move a sprite with the movement of background.

Comment: what have you tried? can you show us your code that moves your sprite and background

Comment: Please don't tag your question "coco" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coco

Answer (score 0):

Use a CCNode to contain both the background and the sprites for your players. Instead of moving the background, move that node.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to handle tilemap based games, and neither of them are very convenient. One way is to leave your character in the center of the screen at all times and move the background underneath it. If your character moves 'right', you simply slide the background to the left, and vice versa. This will give the illusion that the character moves around the map, when in reality it remains centered. Under this paradigm you must remember to convert all detection / collisions into the world's space, and not just the screen space. If you don't convert everything, then your 'range' of collision / detection is limited to the size of the screen.

The second method is to pan the camera over the world. You still keep the character in the middle of the screen, but it actually moves around in the world, and the camera follows. This makes the most intuitive sense to me because it allows you to view the game world as you see the real world. It is also much easier to deal with collisions because the position of the character and the world 'just work' and don't have to be converted. The downside here is that Cocos2D doesn't make it easy to use CCCamera, and the documentation is a little thin in that respect.

In your particular case, it sounds like you have a CCLayer problem. If your character is inside the layer you are moving, it will indeed remain in the same place relative to the map (as you are describing). Instead, float the character in a different layer on top of the map.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scrolling Parallex and then add the sprite onto the same layer as the background. They will move together.